# Changing system time in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, virtualbox, virtualization, time

I need to change the time on my VirtualBox winxp machine (I have an ubuntu host), but it automatically syncronizes with the host. I need different times on the machines because I'm developing something which won't rely on the client's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the clock, choose "Adjust Date/Time."  The rightmost tab should control syncing the clock with the Internet.  Just turn that off, and you can set any time in WinXP and have it stick.

Comment: I tried that...

Comment: oops, it seems i needed to restart win after changing that option. thanks